# download twitter account timeline

Tags: twitter

How can I download all (or most number) of someone's twitter timeline?
Is there any website can do this, or maybe some application or excel sheet.
I am not that good with API, so anything simple will be good.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the Twitter Timeline REST API and iterate to get up to 3200 tweets from his timeline.

Documentation : https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

If you are using C# I can provide an example using Tweetinvi.

Comment: thanks, I'm not familiar with C# and I'm not using Twitter API directly, but the SharePoint flow that pulls the tweets and store them in a list.